# How can I customize my layout.xml from code before calling setContentView(View) function?

Tags: android, layout, view, customization

I would like to customize my layout definition (declared in `my_layout.xml` file) from code.

Unfortunately I can use `findViewById()` function to find the specific views (defined in `my_layout.xml` file) and customize them from code only after I called  `setContentView(R.layout.my_layout)`.

But what if I want to customize my layout first, before calling `setContentView()`? How can I access the specific views before calling `setContentView()`?

Comment: what do you mean by customize? also you cant access the specific views before calling setContentView

Comment: Be more specific about what you want to customize. You may have to resort to programmatic manipulation after the call to setContentView.

Answer (score 0):

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
RelativeLayout myLayout = (RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, null);
```

Now you can use the views/resources defined in R.layout.my_layout and add to your custom layout.

Answer (score 0):

Using LayoutInflater is solution:

```
LayoutInflater li=(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    LinearLayout v= (LinearLayout)li.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
    Button b=v.findViewById(R.id.button);
    setContentView(v);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
LayoutInflater myInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)myInflater.inflate(R.layout.first_layout, null); 
setContentView(layout);
```

Answer (score 0):

`onCreateView` is there for just this purpose. Just override it in your activity or fragment and in there you can customize your views.